# I.E vs Chrome display differences

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, internet-explorer

Just wondering if there is any information about on some difference between Chrome and I.E when rendering some displays from an ASP.NET mvc web app.

For example

```
[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Incorrect format or missing date")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
```

in I.E it is just a plain white box to enter characters where as chrome displays dd/mm/yyyy and keeps that format.

Same with time:

```
[DataType(DataType.Time, ErrorMessage = "Incorrect time")]             
//[RequiredIfTrue("MondayTrue", ErrorMessage ="Day has been marked as working")]
public DateTime? MondayStart { get; set; }
```

plain white box in I.E where as chrome has it --:--

Is there a way to get these attributes to work in I.E?

I.e html line

```
<input name="StartDate" class="div-form-control text-box single-line" id="txtStartDate" type="date" value="" data-val-date="The field StartDate must be a date." data-val="true">
```

chrome html line

```
<input class="div-form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field StartDate must be a date." id="txtStartDate" name="StartDate" type="date" value="">
```

should have added, im using I.E 11 so thought this would have worked.

in my MVC layout page,

these partial views are rendered in the detailview div:

```
<div class="containerBody">
    <div id="detailView"></div>       
</div>
```

View

```
 <div style="display: table-row;">               
                <div class="div-label-text" , style="display: table-cell"> @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate) </div>
                <div class="div-EditorFor" , style="display: table-cell"> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "div-form-control", id = "txtStartDate" } }) </div>
                <div class="div-val-cell" , style="display: table-cell"> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: This is more an HTML issue. Perhaps edit your question and put in the HTML produced

Comment: added the HTML lines for the datebox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you rending the view model property? If you use @Html.EditorFor, it would output input type="date", which is not supported by non html5 compliant old browsers and IE. Take a look here [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=date) to review date and time input field compatibility across browsers.
I would suggest using [Jquery date picker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker)

Comment: @JQuery none of the IE versions support Date and time html5 input types

Answer (score 1):

This depends on which version of IE you are using. Older IE versions don't support type="date" as its an HTML 5 attribute. Chrome's support for HTML 5has always been better. Check out http://blogs.artinsoft.net/Mrojas/archive/2013/01/30/The-inputtype=date-in-Internet-Explorer-%28IE%29-9-and-10.aspx

BTW, those bits of HTML are written the same in both browsers, the difference is how its rendered.

Comment: As you asked so nicely. No.

Comment: Asked what so nicely? sorry I wasn't trying to be rude, last time I added please and thanks you I had a bunch of people edit them to take them out.

Did give you plus 1 for the information

Comment: More detail: The version of IE you are using does not support the HTML 5 <input type="date" ../> but chrome does, that is why you get the differences in behavior. As Mahesh suggested use Jquery date picker or something similar.

Comment: Thanks, Chrome is fine for use, it was more of a general question to see why it was different, its not just date this doesn't work for.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: The differences are because each browser supports HTML 5 differently and to different levels.